# A continuous bounded function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ can be increasing or not?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$  be  a continuous  and  bounded  function , then

$a$) $f$ has a fixed point.

$b$) $f$ cannot be increasing

$c$) $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$  exists.

Now  I  think  $a$)  is  correct.  For $f$   being  continuous  and  bounded  there  is  a  positive  integer  say $M$  such  that  $$|f(x)| < M$$ i.e. $$-M < f(x) < M$$ i.e. $$f(-M) > -M \text{ and } f(M) < M$$ i.e. if  we  take $$g(x)=f(x)-x$$  then  it  is  continuous  and $$g(-M) < 0$$ and  $$g(M) > 0$$
and  hence  there  is  a  point $x_0$  such  that  $$g(x_0)=0$$ i.e. $$f(x_0)=x_0$$

[image]

For  option $c$) I  drew  this  graph thinking  it  would  be  possible  for   the  function $f$  to  be  increasing  with  $y=M$  being  its  asymptote  but  I  am  not  sure  since  could  not  get  the  analytic  definition  of  this . So  if  $c$)  is  wrong  then  it  can  be  increasing  then $f(x)$  being increasing  and  bounded will not  the  limit  in  $c$)  exist? But  may  be  not  always .  Need  little  help  on  proving  $b$)  and  $c$)  wrong .

Thanks..

Comment: Your argument for the existence of a fixed point is correct except that I think you've got two inequalities going in the wrong direction. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

b) is incorrect. Consider the function $f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$.

c) is incorrect. Consider the function $f(x) = \sin(x)$.